# If I use addmargin in scrextend, it jams everything together

Tags: formatting, koma-script

I notice that when I use `addmargin` in the `scrextend` package, inside the addmargin environment, vertical spacing gets weird.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\newtheorem*{claim}{Claim}

\begin{document}
Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative $R$ algebras.
\begin{claim}
A map $A \xrightarrow{\varphi}B$ is an $R$ algebra map $\iff \varphi(f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)) = f(\varphi x_1, \dotsc, \varphi x_n)\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall f$
\end{claim}
\begin{proof}
$\varphi(r_0 + r_1 \alpha + \dotsb + r_n \alpha^n) = r_0 + r_1 \varphi(\alpha) + \dotsb + r_n \varphi(\alpha)^n$.
\end{proof}
\begin{addmargin}[3em]{3cm}
Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative $R$ algebras.
\begin{claim}
A map $A \xrightarrow{\varphi}B$ is an $R$ algebra map $\iff \varphi(f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)) = f(\varphi x_1, \dotsc, \varphi x_n)\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall f$
\end{claim}
\begin{proof}
$\varphi(r_0 + r_1 \alpha + \dotsb + r_n \alpha^n) = r_0 + r_1 \varphi(\alpha) + \dotsb + r_n \varphi(\alpha)^n$.
\end{proof}
\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

Produces [image]

Answer (score 1):

`addmargin` and `claim` are both lists. For the inner list `\topsep` is 0pt and `amsthm` uses `\topsep` as preskip and postskip for the theorems.

There is a **prelease of the next KOMA version 3.22** which works with your code as expected. You can download/install it from the [KOMA-Script website](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}[2016/10/21]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{claim}{Claim}

\begin{document}
Used KOMA-Script version: \KOMAScriptVersion

Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative $R$ algebras.
\begin{claim}
A map $A \xrightarrow{\varphi}B$ is an $R$ algebra map $\iff \varphi(f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)) = f(\varphi x_1, \dotsc, \varphi x_n)\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall f$
\end{claim}
\begin{proof}
$\varphi(r_0 + r_1 \alpha + \dotsb + r_n \alpha^n) = r_0 + r_1 \varphi(\alpha) + \dotsb + r_n \varphi(\alpha)^n$.
\end{proof}
\begin{addmargin}[3em]{3cm}
Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative $R$ algebras.
\begin{claim}
A map $A \xrightarrow{\varphi}B$ is an $R$ algebra map $\iff \varphi(f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)) = f(\varphi x_1, \dotsc, \varphi x_n)\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall f$
\end{claim}
\begin{proof}
$\varphi(r_0 + r_1 \alpha + \dotsb + r_n \alpha^n) = r_0 + r_1 \varphi(\alpha) + \dotsb + r_n \varphi(\alpha)^n$.
\end{proof}
\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As a workaround for KOMA-Script **version 3.21 or older** you can use

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
%amsthm theorem in list hack (suggested by Markus Kohm)
\AtBeginDocument{\thm@space@setup\renewcommand*{\thm@space@setup}{}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%Workaround for KOMA-Script version 3.21 or older:
\makeatletter
%amsthm theorem in list hack (suggested by Markus Kohm)
\AtBeginDocument{\thm@space@setup\renewcommand*{\thm@space@setup}{}}
\makeatother

\newtheorem*{claim}{Claim}

\begin{document}
Used KOMA-Script version: \KOMAScriptVersion

Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative $R$ algebras.
\begin{claim}
A map $A \xrightarrow{\varphi}B$ is an $R$ algebra map $\iff \varphi(f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)) = f(\varphi x_1, \dotsc, \varphi x_n)\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall f$
\end{claim}
\begin{proof}
$\varphi(r_0 + r_1 \alpha + \dotsb + r_n \alpha^n) = r_0 + r_1 \varphi(\alpha) + \dotsb + r_n \varphi(\alpha)^n$.
\end{proof}
\begin{addmargin}[3em]{3cm}
Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative $R$ algebras.
\begin{claim}
A map $A \xrightarrow{\varphi}B$ is an $R$ algebra map $\iff \varphi(f(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)) = f(\varphi x_1, \dotsc, \varphi x_n)\,\,\,\,\,\, \forall f$
\end{claim}
\begin{proof}
$\varphi(r_0 + r_1 \alpha + \dotsb + r_n \alpha^n) = r_0 + r_1 \varphi(\alpha) + \dotsb + r_n \varphi(\alpha)^n$.
\end{proof}
\end{addmargin}
\end{document}
```